# Python fromtimestamp OSError

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp, oserror

For some reason when constructing datetimes using fromtimestamp, I get a

> "OSError [Errno22] Invalid Argument"

when I use negative times less than -43200 (-12hrs).
I am on Win7 64-bit and python 3.5.1. Here's code that produces the error.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-43200, pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 12, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-43201, pytz.utc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The sample uses pytz to simplify timezone information, but the error also occurs without it.

Comment: Here your two lines are similar first one print the value second throw error . so i think there is some indent error or something else.. so try to catch exception using except OSError as e: then put your error ..

Comment: It's not a syntax error. This example is intentionally simple to show the minimum required to cause the error. I initially found the limit in a for loop.

Comment: same issue for me was a [bug in python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413138/python-3-6-datetime-fromtimestamp-throws-error-when-given-0)

Answer (score 70):

If you get this error and you're not using an obviously wrong timestamp, check your units.

`fromtimestamp` expects a timestamp in seconds, whereas it's quite common to get timetstamps in milliseconds (e.g. I found this when trying to parse a timestamp produced from Moment.js in a calendar widget).

Take the timestamp 1523443804214 - it's 11th April 2018, about 15 minutes before I made this post. According to [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), no problem, but note: ***"Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:"***.

In Python this returns an OSError:

```
In [15]: datetime.fromtimestamp(1523443804214.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0c8efd251031> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.fromtimestamp(1523443804214.0)
```

However if we divide by a thousand:

```
In [17]: datetime.fromtimestamp(1523443804.214)
Out[17]: datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 11, 50, 4, 214000)
```

the result is what we expect.

Comment: I needed to see this spelled out to me. This is the exact reason I was getting my error. I was using JSON PowerShell dates in Python and they are using milliseconds.

Answer (score 26):

To solve this problem, divide the timestamp value by 1000.

In Windows, the timestamp number is multiplied by a factor of a 1000.

Answer (score 20):

If the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C `localtime()` or `gmtime()` functions, `datetime.fromtimestamp()` may raise an exception like you're seeing.

On Windows platform, this range can sometimes be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038.  I have never seen this problem on a Linux system.

If you have a negative timestamp `t` on Windows and are encountering this error, here is a workaround:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetime.fromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(seconds=t)     # localtime
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(seconds=t)  # utc
```

Comment: I faced this same problem on Windows 10 (and python 3.6.5), when timestamp was equal 0.

Comment: Just have to divide the timestamp by 1000. I tested over Windows 10 and Linux, both work and give the right answer.

Comment: Me as well @EdwardWeinert did you figure it out ?

Comment: This is the correct answer for OP's case with a 1969 date

Comment: I am facing the same problem with e.g. `.datetime.fromtimestamp(-662688000)` which is `datetime.datetime(1949, 1, 1, 1, 0)` on Windows and it works correctly on macOS and Linux. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: @Primoz Added a possible workaround to the answer.  I think the correct result is `datetime.datetime(1949, 1, 1, 0, 0)`, not `datetime.datetime(1949, 1, 1, 1, 0)`, isn't it? Perhaps your machine is configured in a [UTC+1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B01:00) timezone and you've used a localtime.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are correct it is `datetime.datetime(1949, 1, 1, 0, 0)`. I copied the result from the console and am in UTC+1 so this is the reason for a different result.

Comment: @Primoz  Ok, that explains it.  Ni za kaj!

Answer (score 12):

[@wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41400321/7232335) is correct, but anyone else arriving here might be interested in testing it (adjust range if you wish):

```
import datetime
import platform
print(
    "Running on Python ver.{} on {} {}\n" \
    .format(
        platform.python_version(),
        platform.system(),
        platform.release()
        )
)
for timestamp in range(1, 100000000):
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        break
print(
    "Smallest accepted Unix timestamp by {}: '{}' ({})" \
    .format(platform.system(), timestamp, dt)
)
```

What I got was:

```
A:\src\X.utilities>test.py
Running on Python ver.3.6.1 on Windows 7

Smallest accepted Unix timestamp by Windows: '86400' (1970-01-02 02:00:00)
```

Comment: `Running on Python ver.3.9.1 on Windows 10`
`Smallest accepted Unix timestamp by Windows: '1' (1970-01-01 01:00:01)`

Answer (score 1):

Late contribution, but I think it's important to emphasize that this is 1) platform-specific and 2) that there might be a platform-agnostic solution.

quoting from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

> `fromtimestamp()` may raise `OverflowError`, if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C `localtime()` or `gmtime()` functions, and `OSError` on `localtime()` or `gmtime()` failure. It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038.

"restricted to years in 1970 through 2038" basically means just the positive range of a signed 32 bit integer representing seconds. Note that this is not a general limitation of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number). Nevertheless, negative numbers can fail, e.g. in the following code, `Python 3.10` on `Windows 10`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(-86400)) # 1969-12-31

>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The platform-agnostic alternative would be

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print(datetime(1970,1,1)+timedelta(seconds=-86400))

>>>
1969-12-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score -9):

A timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1st 1970, and this is always a positive value.

Comment: –1 for the unnecessary condescension.  Actually, using `fromtimestamp` with a negative number usually works fine, but it's platform-dependent.

Comment: @wim –1 for using –1 instead of -1