# Python 3.6 datetime.fromtimestamp throws error when given 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

In Python 3.5.2 this works:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
returns -> datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

In Python 3.6, however, I get

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
-> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I can't find any change to the function in the docs. I am curious why this breaks my scripts now and where I can find the reasons.

Can anybody shed some light on that?

[image: Python 3.6 REPL datetime.fromtimestamp error]

Comment: Cannot reproduce w/ Python 3.6.0 @ Linux
Did you install Python 3.6 from the repos or otherwise?

Comment: Just checked on python 3.6.0 and get same error while works for 3.5.1 and 3.4.3 on Windows 10

Comment: Bug is present in Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug introduced in Python 3.6.0 on Windows only.
Details: https://bugs.python.org/issue29097

Patches are in the works and it will likely be fixed soon.

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't show up on Google.Thank you!

Comment: Did you find the answer? is it fixed yet?