# function for date_parser and read_csv not working

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have 3 different datasets that I'm reading in with pd.read_csv. One of the columns of the data is time in seconds and I would like to use a function that I made for the pd.read_csv date_parser argument. It works fine when all the data is integers. However, the function I made doesn't work when I have a string or float. I think the problem is occuring at datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs) part of my function. Does anybody know how I can get this to work for all my datasets. I'm completely stuck. I put a sample below of how the 3 different datasets look.

dataset 1

> 555, 1404803485, 800
>
> 555, 1408906759, 900

dataset 2

> 231, 1404803485, pass
>
> 231, 1404803490, fail

dataset 3

> 16010925, 1403890894, 40.5819880696
>
> 16010925, 1903929273, 40.5819880696

```
def dateparse(time_in_secs):

if isinstance(time_in_secs, str):
    if time_in_secs == '\\N':
        time_in_secs = 0

tm = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))
tm = tm - datetime.timedelta(
    minutes=tm.minute % 10, seconds=tm.second, microseconds=tm.microsecond)
return tm


pd.read_csv('dataset_here.csv',
           delimiter=',', index_col=[0,1], parse_dates=['Timestamp'], 
                date_parser=dateparse, names=['Serial', 'Timestamp', 'result'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need convert time to `0` for all strings, for `float`s your solution working nice:

```
def dateparse(time_in_secs):

    if isinstance(time_in_secs, str):
        #https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372194
        #time_in_secs = 86400
        time_in_secs = 0

    #print (time_in_secs)
    tm = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))
    tm = tm - datetime.timedelta(
    minutes=tm.minute % 10, seconds=tm.second, microseconds=tm.microsecond)
    return tm
```

More general solution - try convert value to float and if not possible assign default value:

```
def dateparse(time_in_secs):

    if isinstance(time_in_secs, str):
        try:
            time_in_secs = float(time_in_secs)
        except ValueError:
            #https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372194
            #time_in_secs = 86400
            time_in_secs = 0

    #print (time_in_secs)
    tm = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))
    tm = tm - datetime.timedelta(
    minutes=tm.minute % 10, seconds=tm.second, microseconds=tm.microsecond)
    return tm
```

**Sample**: Tested under windows:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def dateparse(time_in_secs):

    if isinstance(time_in_secs, str):
        try:
            time_in_secs = float(time_in_secs)
        except ValueError:
            #https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372194
            #time_in_secs = 0
            time_in_secs = 86400

    print (time_in_secs)
    tm = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))
    tm = tm - datetime.timedelta(
    minutes=tm.minute % 10, seconds=tm.second, microseconds=tm.microsecond)
    return tm

temp=u"""16010925,test,40.5819880696
16010925,1903929273,40.5819880696"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), index_col=[0,1], parse_dates=['Timestamp'], 
                date_parser=dateparse, names=['Serial', 'Timestamp', 'result'])

print (df)
                                 result
Serial   Timestamp                     
16010925 1970-01-02 01:00:00  40.581988
         2030-05-02 07:10:00  40.581988

print (df.index.get_level_values(1))
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-02 01:00:00', '2030-05-02 07:10:00'], 
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Timestamp', freq=None)
```