# Error22 - invalid argument on a simple datetime conversion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a bit stumped by this I'm not going to lie but I'm currently having an invalid argument error thrown at me every time I try to convert a 13 character epoch to a readable date. This works without issue earlier on within the script, the part is erroring out on is the following:

```
print (msgTime)
messageTime=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(msgTime)
```

The value of 'msgTime' is gathered from an SQL Database and is returned as : 1540406475702

The exact error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 380, in <module>
    messageTime=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(msgTime)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I know Its likely something silly or small but I just can't see what is up, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of msgTime?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494983/python-fromtimestamp-oserror

Comment: read official docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html your func is ok, but msgTime has wrong value; if you try with different number - it just works; there is explanation on typical gotchas as well.

Answer (score 1):

The eopch time wont include milliseconds so currently would only be 10 digits long. Yours is 13, you can get rid of the extra milliseconds by floor dividing by 1000

```py
from datetime import datetime
msgTime = 1540406475702
print (msgTime)
messageTime=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(msgTime//1000)
print(messageTime)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1540406475702
2018-10-24 18:41:15
```

**UPDATE**

Having looked at the source code of datetime and how it implements fromtimestamp if you wanted to pass milliseconds you can do it by passing the values as a float where the 3 digits after the decimal point represents the milliseconds. Below is an extract from the datetime module

> ```
> @classmethod
> def _fromtimestamp(cls, t, utc, tz):
>     """Construct a datetime from a POSIX timestamp (like time.time()).
>     A timezone info object may be passed in as well.
>     """
>     frac, t = _math.modf(t)
>     us = round(frac * 1e6)
>     if us >= 1000000:
>         t += 1
>         us -= 1000000
>     elif us < 0:
>         t -= 1
>         us += 1000000
>
>     converter = _time.gmtime if utc else _time.localtime
>     y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, weekday, jday, dst = converter(t)
>     ss = min(ss, 59)    # clamp out leap seconds if the platform has them
>     result = cls(y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, us, tz)
> ```

So you can pass milli / micro seconds if you pass them as the digits after the decimal place. Is it possible when this was working before that your epoch was second followed by a decimal place then the milliseconds?

```py
from datetime import datetime
msgTime = 1540406475.702
print (msgTime)
messageTime=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(msgTime)
print(messageTime)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1540406475.702
2018-10-24 18:41:15.702000
```

Comment: Thanks sorry for this.. 

Weirdly this worked before for a 13 character timestamp that was throwing me off..

Comment: Without sounding to blunt i dont see how thats possible based on your current code.

Comment: @TrueSlawter This was still bugging me so i had a look at the source code for datetime. Is it possible that when it worked before your epoch was coming as `1540406475.702` as datetime will happily process that and calculate in the milliseconds etc. So is it coming now as `1540406475702` instead? because the only way dateimte identifies milli / nano seconds in an epoch is if they are after the decimal place.

Comment: It does appear that was the case Chris! thank you once again and sorry for wasting your time and so on.

Comment: @TrueSlawter you are welcome and it wasnt a waste of time. I also learned from it as had never really looked at the date time implementation before so i got something out of it too.