# OSError 22 Invalid Argument [Converting Epoch Timestamp To Human Time]

Tags: python, epoch

I am trying to convert an epoch timestamp to datetime.

I have tried using datetime.fromtimestamp but it gives me an invalid argument error.

Here is my code:

```
def get_last_login(name):
    url = f"https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={API_KEY}&name={name}"
    res = requests.get(url)
    data = res.json()
    if data["player"] is None:
        return None

    lastlogouttime = (data["player"]["lastLogout"])
    timedate = datetime.fromtimestamp(lastlogouttime)
    return format(timedate)
```

lastlogouttime returns an epoch timestamp from the hypixel api.

Edit:
Full traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in command lastlogin:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deagan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Deagan\Desktop\hybot\bot.py", line 46, in lastlogin
    lastlogin = hypixelcustomwrapper.get_last_login(name)
  File "C:\Users\Deagan\Desktop\hybot\hypixelcustomwrapper.py", line 74, in get_last_login
    timedate = datetime.fromtimestamp(lastlogouttime)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Import statement:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
```

What it gets from the api:

```
"lastLogout":1589588947970"
```

What it should return:

```
1589588947970
```

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback, and an example of the value you get for `lastlogouttime`? Also, what does your `import` statement look like? The correct way to use the `fromtimestamp` function is `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` is you're using `import datetime`.

Comment: @PrateekDewan done.

Comment: Try `timedate = datetime.fromtimestamp(lastlogouttime/1000)`? The value seems to be in milliseconds, whereas the function takes seconds as input. This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494983/python-fromtimestamp-oserror

Comment: @PrateekDewan Thank you! it worked. it outputs ```2020-05-15 17:29:07.970000``` how can i remove everything after 17:29?

Comment: `datetime.fromtimestamp(lastlogouttime/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`