# python3 fromtimestamp generates OSError

Tags: python, windows, datetime

We encountered an interesting mtime problem we encountered in the field. I'm planning to file a bug report, but wanted to get outside perspective.

A file stored on a windows server had the last-modified date '1/1/4501' (that's the year 4501). `os.path.getmtime()` returns a valid timestamp, but when we try to pass this back into `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` we get an `OSError`.

There are several discussions on SO that talk around this issue, for example: [Python fromtimestamp OSError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494983/python-fromtimestamp-oserror).  However, in most of the cases we could find, the OP were dealing with manufactured dates that clearly were outside the platform's supported epoch range. Generating an `OSError` when the date exceeds the epoch support on Windows is consistent with the python docs.

In our case, the date is clearly supported by Windows as evidenced by it's storage in the filesystem.  Further, we can reproduce the situation using the cygwin `touch` utility.

```
>>> import os, datetime
>>> os.system('touch -d "4501-01-01" file.txt')
>>> t = os.path.getmtime('file.txt')
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What's interesting is we can manually convert it with reference to the epoch

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t)
datetime.datetime(4501, 1, 1, 5, 0)
```

We used Windows 10-Pro for our tests running python 3.8.1.

Comment: what's your question??

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu. `t` was `79870690800.0`. I assume you are using a 64 bit python?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `t` on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is not a bug, it's a documented limitation of the platform's `localtime()/gmtime()`. While the `datetime` class itself can handle arbitrary dates, any references to `timestamp` requires a pass through the platform's localtime system. In my case it's Windows 10, 64bit.

According to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-s-localtime32-s-localtime64-s?view=vs-2019

> _localtime64_s, which uses the __time64_t structure, allows dates to be expressed up through 23:59:59, January 18, 3001, coordinated
>   universal time (UTC)

Passing in a value greater than the year 3001 causes `localtime64_s` to return **EINVAL**. According to python docs:

> This may raise OverflowError, if the timestamp is out of the range of
>   values supported by the platform C localtime() function, and OSError
>   on localtime() failure.

The later is what we are seeing.