# Getting [Errno 22] Invalid argument in datetime.utcfromtimestamp()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, datetime, netcdf

I am using python 3.10.6. I have this function which takes a netcdf file and assigns dmin and dmax the minimum and maximum dates of the time index from that file's data. Whenever the dmin is below 1970 (i.e. 1969 and below), I get the following error:

> xmin = datetime.utcfromtimestamp((dmin - sec0) / sec1).date() OSError:
> [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Here is my code:

```
def get_minmax_date(data):
    dmin = data['time'].values.min()
    dmax = data['time'].values.max()

    sec0 = np.datetime64(0, 's')
    sec1 = np.timedelta64(1, 's')
    xmin = datetime.utcfromtimestamp((dmin - sec0) / sec1).date()
    xmax = datetime.utcfromtimestamp((dmax - sec0) / sec1).date() + timedelta(days=1)

    return xmin, xmax
```

I know it's a bug in the datetime library but Is there any workaround?

Comment: Double check what `(dmin - sec0) / sec1` and the other gives. The docs say that error is due to a `gmtime` failure if argument is too large.

Comment: ```print((dmin - sec0))```
```print((dmax - sec0))```
Output:
-946771200000000000 nanoseconds
-757386000000000000 nanoseconds

Comment: @FObersteiner Yes I am. The solution suggests using ```.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)``` but where do I put this in my code?

Comment: @FObersteiner nah, still gives the same error

Comment: This is not a "bug" in datetime, it's a design flaw in Unix (long before but inherited by Linux).  The definition of "timestamp" here is a Unix time_t value, which by definition is "seconds since 1/1/1970".

Comment: The "flaw" is the shortsightedness of the original Unix designers, in choosing a time format that would not work before 1970 nor after 2037.

Comment: @TimRoberts I wonder where you got that info from, and if it is still up-to-date. Please have a look at [this section on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number). Coming back to the OP, I can reproduce the problem with negative input numbers to `utcfromtimestamp` on Windows 10 but not on Linux. So I would still argue that this is a fault of a platform implementation, not Unix time. Still, avoiding Unix time methods and using datetime / timedelta instead seems to be the best option here.

Comment: I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75853010/10197418) to the linked duplicate to clarify this.

Comment: @FObersteiner -- I was there.  The Unix `time` syscall returned seconds since 1/1/1970 as a 32-bit value and still does today.  Hopefully, advance planning can help us have 1/19/2038 go as smoothly as 1/1/2000.