# Code raises OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument while using time() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, timestamp

why do this code return OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument? From what I found it should only be raised if you use functions that interacts with the OS or uses paths witch isn't in my code.

Here's my code:

```
if getattr(time.localtime(), 'tm_wday') == 2:
    a = time.strptime('2023-10-17 15:20:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    b = int(time.mktime(a))
    while True:
        y = str(getattr(time.gmtime(b - time.time()), 'tm_hour')), ':', str(
            getattr(time.gmtime(b - time.time()), 'tm_min')), ':', str(getattr(time.gmtime(b - time.time()), 'tm_sec'))
        x = ''.join(y)
        print(x, end='\r')
```

And here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\School\Desktop\final countdown.py", line 7, in <module>
    y = str(getattr(time.gmtime(b - time.time()), 'tm_hour')), ':', str(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I tried adding an int() here and there but the result is the same. The code worked fine last time I tried it, but breaks now despite me not having done any changes to it since.

Comment: Are you sure that's your code? A copy'n'paste of your code (add import time) does not give any error. Your infinite loop is intriguing

Comment: Yes. As I said in the post, it worked fine before, but broke this morning despite me having done no modifications to it. As for the loop, I just do Ctrl+C to break it, even tough I plan on using the keyboard module to break it with esc later.

Comment: probably duplicate of [Python fromtimestamp OSError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37494983/10197418)

Comment: @FObersteiner I thought so too, but since I get my time from the time.time() function, it is already in seconds and dividing it by 1000 to turn the miliseconds into seconds just further breaks the code.

Comment: I don't think this is about milliseconds vs. seconds ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460238/10197418) answer is totally misleading imho), it's about what the underlying C functions on your platform can handle as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering i found that doing the b-time.time() outside of the time.gmtime() function and declaring it before in a z function works
here's the revamped code:

```
import time

if getattr(time.localtime(), 'tm_wday') == 0:
    while True:
        a = time.strptime('' + str(getattr(time.localtime(),'tm_year')) + '-' +str(getattr(time.localtime(), 'tm_mon')) + '-' + str(getattr(time.localtime(), 'tm_mday')) + ' 15:20:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        b = int(time.mktime(a))
        z = int(b) - time.time()
        y = (str(f"{int(getattr(time.gmtime(z), 'tm_hour')):02}"),':',str(f"{int(getattr(time.gmtime(z),'tm_min')):02}"), ':',str(f{int(getattr(time.gmtime(z), 'tm_sec')):02}"))x = ''.join(y)
        print(x, end='\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to passing a negative value to `time.gmtime`, You should update the `time.strptime('2023-10-18 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` Date and time so that the `b - time.time()` gives positive value. `b = time.mktime(a)` the convert to 'int' is not needed.